# SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: ssl, smtp

I'm getting these errors when sending emails using our server's SMTP:

> SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol
>
> Failed to enable crypto

What does it mean and what's the fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, it is a SSL error. You should only use SSL if it is needed and it needs to be supported on both ends. If your SMTP is connecting on port 25, chances are that it isn't SSL enabled.

Without more details on your actual connection and configuration, it is difficult to give a better answer.

Comment: Which is not SSL-enabled? The SMTP server?